# Slash-commands are not available on the discord server

Tags: python, discord.py

After I added my bot written discord-interactions and discord.py to the server, the available slash-commands stopped showing, although they were previously available on the same server. Also commands are available in direct messages. In server permissions are allowed to use Slash-commands. How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure that the invite link have application.commands permission in [discord developer](https://discord.com/developers/application) and use application command in the server. Also, you should probably rerun your bot and wait for 1 hour or less for Discord to implement all slash commands into server.

Answer (score 1):

Slash commands, if not explicitly registered to a group of servers will take roughly an hour to register globally. I suggest waiting and coming back if it still doesn't work.