# discord.js command handler not working/registering

Tags: node.js, discord.js

The command handler that I have at the moment is not registering the new commands that I'm creating.

I'm attempting to make a simple kick command to kick the user, and the kick command is not showing up on my bot. I tried kicking the bot and re-inviting it with new permissions. Nothing. The code is below.

Code in slash-register.js

```
const { Routes } = require('discord-api-types/v9');
const { token } = require('./config.json');
const fs = require('node:fs');
const commands = [];
const commandList = new Map()

module.exports = (updateCommands) => {
const commands = [];
const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

// Place your client and guild ids here
const clientId = '908818107093622814'; 
const guildId = '961765341451665498';

for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
    commands.push(command.data.toJSON());
    commandList.set(command.data.name, command.run)
}

const rest = new REST({ version: '9' }).setToken(token);

if (updateCommands) {
    (async () => {
        try {
            console.log('Started refreshing application (/) commands.');
    
            console.log(commands)
            /* await rest.put(
                 Routes.applicationCommands(clientId),
                 { body: commands },
             ); */
            await rest.put(
                Routes.applicationGuildCommands(clientId, guildId),
                { body: commands },
            );
    
    
            console.log('Successfully reloaded application (/) commands.');
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
        }
    })();
    }
}



module.exports.commands = commandList;
```

code in kick.js

```
module.exports.data = new SlashCommandBuilder()
.setName("kick")
.setDescription("Kick the user selected.")
.addUserOption(option => option.setName("person").setDescription("The person to kick."));

module.exports.run = (bot,interaction) => {
    let permissions = interaction.member.permissions;
    if(!permissions.has("MANAGE_MESSAGES")) return interaction.editReply({content: "You don't have the correct permissions."})
    interaction.editReply({
        content: "You are trying to kick a member."
    })
}
```

Code in index.js

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const Bot = new Discord.Client({ intents: [Discord.Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Discord.Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES] });
const { token } = require('./config.json')
require("./slash-register.js")()
let commands = require("./slash-register.js").commands;

// Bot actions
Bot.on('ready', () => {
  console.log(`Logged in as ${Bot.user.tag}!`);

  let commands = Bot.application.commands
});

Bot.on('interactionCreate', async interaction => {
  if(!interaction.isCommand()) return; 
  let name = interaction.commandName;
  let options = interaction.options;

  let commandMethod = commands.get(name);
  if(!commandMethod) return;
  
  await interaction.deferReply();
  
  commandMethod(Bot, interaction)
})

// Token
Bot.login(token);
```

I am aware that the kick command is incomplete, that's due to me learning discord.js v13.
Thanks!

-h3lped

> PS: I have heard that you have to wait about an hour to load the slash commands but the bot has been running for over an hour (at the time of writing this) and it's still not showing up.

Comment: These might solve your problem: [Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69554579/slash-commands-are-not-available-on-the-discord-server), `Slash command` should wait for almost `1 hour` to register your command.

Comment: @新Acesyyy thanks for telling me but the bot has been running for over an hour and it's still not showing up. But the way the command handler was written it's suppose to show instantly.